# Parser Error in ASP.net when new forms are added

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, webforms

Like the title says, this only happens when I create new items in the project.  Even if I create a new webform which should work by default. (although it would be blank).  Here is an example of an error I get from a fresh webform.  This is my first project in ASP.net.  There is a possibility that I could have inadvertently messed something up which is beyond the scope of my knowledge.  I've spent 3 hours trying to get this to work, please help!

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'TaylorsProfessionalServices.WebForm1'.

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TaylorsProfessionalServices.WebForm1" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


Source File: /WebForm1.aspx    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5483
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? What version of the .NET Framework are you targeting? (To find the latter, right-click your project in Solution Explorer, click Properties, and look on the Application tab.)

Comment: Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM
.Net Framerwork 3.5

Comment: It says it can't load `TaylorsProfessinoalServices.WebForm1` class, and that it should be in `WebForm1.aspx.cs`. Verify that's it's there.

Comment: It sounds to me like something is corrupted.  I would try to repair you Visual Studio installation.

Comment: I have another group member for this project.  He has been doing back end development for about 6 years.  He figured it out in about 10 minutes.  He had access to the entire solution.  I had to delete a specific page and then the rest worked.  I don't understand why but he is going to explain it to me later.  Thanks for the help guys.  I wish I could explain in better detail but I am inexperienced